# Prepend backslashes for every dot

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I'd like to prepend backslasher for every dot which is present in javascript.
For instance:

```
this.is.a.test
```

will give

```
this\\.is\\.a\\.test
```

I tried this :

```
a = "this.is.a.test";
b = a.replace(".","\\.");
```

but b returns `this\.is.a.test` instead of `this\\.is\\.a\\.test`

Backslashes are used to escape strings, so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
a = "this.is.a.test";
b = a.replace(/\./g,"\\.");
//returns "this\.is\.a\.test"
```

for two backslashes do this

```
a = "this.is.a.test";
b = a.replace(/\./g,"\\\\.");
//returns "this\\.is\\.a\\.test"
```

Comment: escuse me, I edited my first post. I need 2 backslashes for every dot. Stackoverflow unescaped my question...

Comment: thanks you for the answer ;) I'll confirm it when SO will allow me to do so